# Create SHA hash and compare it when the source has moved location

Tags: c#, hash, sha

I've created a simple C# program that can hash a file (I'm focusing on images, as opposed to PDF's, text etc) that displays the hash only on the command line. I will create a function to output a file (unsure what type?) so that this can be referenced later.

The idea is that an image will travel from one location to another, and once it reaches the second destination it will be checked by the hashing program once more, locating the hash file associated with it, comparing it, and then producing the result (i.e. it is identical or not). The code I have is not very relevant, hence why I've not posted it - I'm mainly just looking for tips/hints or any documentation that might be of use here!

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Code is important so here it is

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Hash
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            byte[] hashValue = null;
            if (!File.Exists(args[1]))
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(args[1]);
                    fileStream.Position = 0;
                    switch (args[0].ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "SHA512":
                            // Compute the SHA512 hash of the fileStream.
                            hashValue = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(fileStream);
                            return;
                    }
                    if (hashValue != null)
                    {
                        PrintHashData(args[0].ToUpper(), fileStream.Name, hashValue);
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PrintHashData(string algorithm, string fileName, byte[] array)
    {
        Console.Write("File: {0}\r\n{1} Hash: ", fileName, algorithm);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(String.Format("{0:X2}", array[i]));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Request for tips/hints and documentation is not a question. Also you have your tags wrong.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow. The **code is always relevant**. Please, add it to your question with an edit so we can build on that and come up with a solution. Without code for context questions like this are really hard to answer in specific terms.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is.   Maybe there is no question?